# Simple basic Calculator Javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, calculator

First of all it's my first app, I'm trying to code a calculator. When pressing an operator, if there is old one, calculate it and send the result to continue with it to the new process. The calculation process don't go to the second step, anyone can help to make this code work properly?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class main extends Application {
    String num1 ="";
    String num2 ="";
    String op ;
    double result= 0;
    boolean oldop =false ;
    // the GUI component
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button one = new Button("1");
        Button two = new Button("2");
        Button pls = new Button("+");
        Button eql = new Button("=");
        Button ac = new Button("AC");
        Label lbl = new Label("empty");
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(one,two,pls,eql,ac,lbl);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        // The Actions on buttons
        one.setOnAction(e ->
            {
            if(!oldop){
                num1+='1';
            lbl.setText(num1);}
            else {
                num2+='1';
                lbl.setText(num2);}});

        two.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            if(!oldop){
                num1+='2';
                lbl.setText(num1);}
            else {
                num2+='2';
                lbl.setText(num2);}});

        pls.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(!oldop){
                oldop = true;
                op="+";
                lbl.setText(op);}
            else {
                result=calc(num1 , num2 ,op);
                num1=String.valueOf(result);
                num2="";
                op="+";
                lbl.setText(num1+op);
                oldop = true;}});

        eql.setOnAction(e ->{
            if(oldop){
                result=calc(num1 , num2 , op);
                lbl.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                oldop=false;
                num2="";}
            else 
                return;});

        ac.setOnAction(e -> {
            num1="";
            num2="";
            result=0;
            oldop=false;});

    }
    // The calculation method
    public int calc (String n1 , String n2 , String op){
        switch (op) {
        case "+" :
            return Integer.parseInt(n1) + Integer.parseInt(n2) ;
        case "-" :
            return Integer.parseInt(n1) - Integer.parseInt(n2) ;
        case "*" :
            return Integer.parseInt(n1) * Integer.parseInt(n2) ;
        case "/" :
            return Integer.parseInt(n1) / Integer.parseInt(n2) ;
        default :
            return 0;
       }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this [simple calculator example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4344564) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you cannot use the result of an previous operation in the second step, because  you use `String.valueOf` which gives e.g. 3.0 for the int 3 (result of 1+2). This string cannot be used again in `calc` as it cannot be parsed back to an int with `Integer.parseInt.

I would suggest to work with `int` and only convert them to strings for the labels.

An ulgy workaround would be to add the following lines at the beginning of `calc`:

```
    n1=n1.split("\\.")[0];
    n2=n2.split("\\.")[0];
```

Comment: It's work , thanks a lot for you help :) 
i'm really appreciate that ^_^